# Нужно выполнить парсинг

Tags: php, html, парсер

Есть HTML текст для статьи с абзацами <*p> <*/p> и другими тегами. Нужно получить все абзацы в виде PHP массива. Буду между ними вставлять рекламу гугла. Может уже где-то есть решение, чтобы не писать с нуля, изобретая велосипед?

Comment: Примите хотя бы половину верных ответов - дам готовый код :)

Comment: @Sh4dow теперь я знаю что такое «n% принятых».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже сделал.

```
function pParser($text, $addThis = '<p> ------- Please cast to this place your code -------- </p>', $closeTag = '</p>')
{
    $t = $text;
    $ex = explode($closeTag, $text);
    $cnt = count($ex);
    if($cnt <= 10)
    {
        if($cnt >= 4)
        {
            // insert one 
            $pos = round($cnt / 2, 0);
            array_splice($ex, $pos, 0, $addThis);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // insert two
        $pos = round($cnt / 3, 0);
        array_splice($ex, $pos, 0, $addThis);
        array_splice($ex, $pos+$pos+1, 0, $addThis);
    }
    $t = implode('', $ex);
    return $t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Писать код не буду, но как сделать скажу.

1. Лучший способ, да и, наверное, наиболее подходящий для вас - это добавление в конец абзаца, поэтому советую искать в HTML-коде все концы абзаца, юзая "strpos()" или "strstr()", как вам больше удобно.
2. Вставлять текст в найденную позицию. Это можно сделать путем разбиения всего кода на две части - первую до конца найденного абзаца и вторую - после. Затем просто лепите новый текст, соединяя первую часть с вашей рекламой и со второй частью. Сделать это можно, юзая "substr()".

Вот и все. Как видите, не особо и сложно =)